# Qt Creator +CMake+ gmock build issue"gmock.h no such file or diretory" while building project in Qt creator, no issue if build through command line

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I have incorporated GTest in my already existing CMake project by following this [google doc](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project)

If I build my project through the command line there is no error, I am able to run UnitTest Exe. But as I need to debug the unit test, when I run the test in Qt Creator it builds it first but the build failed, throwing the error "gmock/h: no such file or directory". I am not able to understand why this error on Qt Creator only. As few stackoverflow post suggests only gmock.h should get included, that is already there.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I suggest you create a minimal project and provide a link to it here. Thank you.

Comment: The question lacks for the code **in the question** post itself (not *linked*!). See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @SergeiNikulov: thank-you for the suggestion. I created the sample project and was able to find the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake. By mistake, some unwanted line was in CMakeLists.txt which was not creating the issue in the compilation. After Serigei's suggestion, I created a sample project and was able to find the issue.
I have created a git repo of the sample project. Whoever needs help can have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/bisenpiyush/import-gtest-into-existing-cmake-project.git)

Comment: BTW, you'd better check the following examples https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/  and https://github.com/snikulov/google-test-examples how to use google test with CMake.